# Re-render parent component from child form submit

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I'm using bs-stepper as a wizard to fill a long form.

I need to reset the wizard when user submits the form.

Form data is in a state in my parent component containing the stepper wizard:

```
import Step1 from './step1'
import Step2 from './step2'
import StepLast from './steplast'

const Parent = () => {
  const initialState = {
    name: '',
    lastname: '',
    email: '',
    // and so on
  }

  const [data, setData] = useState(initialState)

  const steps = [
    { id: 'step1', title: 'Step One', content: <Step1 data={data}, setData={setData} />},
    { id: 'step2', title: 'Step Two', content: <Step2 data={data}, setData={setData} />},
    { id: 'steplast', title: 'Step Last', content: <StepLast data={data}, setData={setData} initialState={initialState} />}
  ]
  
  return (
  
    <>
     <Wizard steps={steps} />
    </>

  )
}

export default Parent
```

Then, each step fills some of the data:

```
const Step1 = ({data, setData}) => {
  const nextStep = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // go to next step
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Form>
        <Input type='text' onInput={e => setData({...data, name: e.target.value})} />
        <Button type='button' onClick={e => nextStep(e)} />
      </Form>
    </>
  )
}
```

In last step, I submit the form and here I need to "reset" the form and start over:

```
const StepLast = ({data, setData, initialState}) => {
  const saveData = () => {
    axios.post('api/address', data)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response) // this is ok

      setData(initialState) // this is resetting state

      // HERE I NEED TO RESTART THE WIZARD
      
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('error', error)
    }

  }

  return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(saveData)}>
        <Input type='email' onInput={e => setData({...data, email: e.target.value})} />
        <Button type='submit' />
      </Form>
    </>
  )
}
```

I need to start the wizard over after I inserted data on my database. I see in react-devtools that the state is changen to it's initialState, but steps stills have the information entered.

Is there a way to re-render Parent component on form submit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then you have to pass the parent state to the last child component with a state update and you have set the initial value to state.

Comment: I'm passing the state to the last child and setting the initial value. It's written in StepLast component in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `StepLast` component where you spread the object, you forgot to wrap them in {}, it would look something like this in my opinion `setData({...data, email: e.target.value})`.

Also, when you reset the state in the `StepLast` component, you will have to construct a new object, otherwise it wouldn't trigger a re-render, it should look like `setData({...initialState})`

Comment: I was using the curly brackets in my code. I edited the question. This is the solution. I didn't know that creating the new object in state re-rendered the component. Thank you so much.